# General Log Doesn't show/log change

Tags: mysql, innodb

I have been trying to debug something going on the database server, InnoDB as the engine.

It is accessed remotely by several other servers running different programs. The logs on the servers didn't show what had caused certain rows to change.

I enabled the general log to see what query and from what server caused the change to the field. In looking through the log today, I found that on a certain row, a value that had been set on a certain field had been nulled, but I couldn't find any log of the query that had nulled it. Additionally, some rows were deleted and I couldn't find a trace of the query that had deleted them on the general log.

Is there something I am missing? I had read somewhere on the documentation that joins in queries could prevent logging, however, that didn't seem to apply to the general log.

Comment: General query log can be disabled even on a session level...

Comment: Joins do not prevent query logging. I don't know what you read that seemed to say that.

Comment: I wonder how you are searching the logs for the query setting the column to NULL. Keep in mind it may not explicitly assign `columnname = NULL` in the query. It might assign `columnname = <expression>` such that the expression evaluates to NULL. So it might be difficult to search for.

Comment: I was a tracking a unique value in one of the fields, and also tracking the primary key from its table. I didn't see anywhere it was unset to null or even set to anything other than the initial value setting.

Comment: I also have control of ALL the code, so none is enabling or disabling the query log. It's all running from the initial setting.

Comment: FOr joins and query logging, I think I was read it on the binary logging side and was wondering if somehow that carried over.

Comment: Are there `VIEWs` that could be hiding the 'real' table name?  Are there `UNIQUE` keys other than the `PRIMARY KEY`; maybe the `UPDATE` references that?